# Whenever I add an image in html, it permanently lengthens the page

Tags: html, css, image

Tldr; I add image, move image in css, image lengthens the page resulting in blank space above footer. Have to turn in the assigment end of tomorrow (please help). Teacher hasn’t explained a single thing about html in the past year so I don’t know what I’m doing basically.

So I am just a couple days new to html and am rushing to finish a relatively simple website for a school project. I have very limited experience, only having watched an hour full guide on html and just writing.

Anyways I was adding images and blocks of text in my page, everything was well until I noticed the blank space under all my text that eventually connects to my footer.

What I later realized was that whenever I insert an image into my page, set it’s position to relative and move it around, the space it originally took still remains. So basically the length of my page keeps increasing. Now 40% of my page is blank.

For the code that was used, I was only adding blocks of text and images which I moved around in css. If needed I’ll share the whole code.
The css of an image looked like this:

```
.Img5 {width: ; margin-left: ; position: relative; top: -1334;}
```

Comment: Positioning an element with `top`/`left`/`right`/`bottom` only _visually_ moves it around without impacting the content flow. That is, it always leaves its inherent space blank, which is the intended behavior (see this [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)). What you're describing is rarely, if ever, meant for setting up the entire page layout. Whatever you're trying to visually accomplish, consider implementing in `flex` or `grid` layout.

Answer (score 0):

Its because the image is too big u will have to change the width and height to something smaller so they do not take all your space